# Highcharts API changed? Scatter doesn't work like before

Tags: highcharts

Suddenly, our charts stopped working correctly. Scatter point changed from red to black. And some of them are missing. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/dbX4F/2/ - this worked fine until Friday 22th in the afternoon (GMT). Do we have to recode?

The initial code had been taken from the Demo site...

```
var data = [
    [-1.0370901525, -0.2242744267],
    [-0.9570242763, 0.1297600865],
    [-0.8440818191, 0.0616363287],
    [-1.0407160521, 0.3065044880],
    [-1.0265066624, 0.3317940235],
    [-0.9633093774, 0.3405199349],
    [-0.9326101542, 0.3265898228],
    [-0.9424129128, 0.3695831895],
    [-0.9341677129, 0.3855949938],
    [-0.9256171882, 0.4086754620],
    [-0.9600118995, 0.4446559548],
    [-0.7863433361, 0.3159923553]
];

var scatter = [-0.6306822896, -0.4136320949, -0.3912227452, -0.3671057820, -0.3473563194, -0.3113947213, -0.3030101657, -0.2864148617, -0.2742863595, -0.2584708631, -0.2576779723, ];

.........

                events: {

                    // listen to the selection event on the master chart to update the
                    // extremes of the detail chart
                    selection: function (event) {
                        var extremesObject = event.xAxis[0],
                            min = extremesObject.min,
                            max = extremesObject.max,
                            detailData = [],
                            detailScatter = [],
                            xAxis = this.xAxis[0];

                        // reverse engineer the last part of the data
                        jQuery.each(data, function (i, interval) {
                            if (i > min && i < max) {
                                detailData.push([i, interval[0], interval[1]]);
                                detailScatter.push([i, scatter[i]]);
                            }
                        });

                        // move the plot bands to reflect the new detail span
                        xAxis.removePlotBand('selection');
                        xAxis.addPlotBand({
                            id: 'selection',
                            from: min,
                            to: max,
                            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
                        });

                        detailChart.series[0].setData(detailData);
                        detailChart.series[1].setData(detailScatter);

                        return false;
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: I was hoping that some Highcharts company member could answer this ("Ask support question on stackoverflow")...

What did change in the API in respect of Chatter display type? I couldn't find any information in the release announcement.

Answer (score 0):

You can control color by setting colors option http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors or set scatter serie color http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.color

Comment: I'm just wondering why the code worked before and now it has some issues with the new API. It would be nice to know what has changed. The debugger says that `event.xAxis[0]` is not defined in "selection" event callback function... And the default colors have changed?